# como sobrescrever o método save do models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Estou tentando sobrescrever o método save do models para que quando for criado um novo livro o mesmo seja salvo e exportado de imediato para um arquivo .json, essa seria uma forma de backup automático, porém quando cadastro um novo livro ele exporta todos os itens menos o ultimo cadastrado, mas ele deveria exportar todos, alguém poderia me dar um exemplo por gentileza de como sobrescrever esse método de forma correta??

```
def save(self, filename="books", *args, **kwargs):
    get = serializers.serialize("json", Books.objects.all())
    bkp = open("backup/" + filename + ".json", "w")
    bkp.write(get)
    super(Books, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Esse método está dentro de alguma classe?

Comment: Sim, esta na classe do meu model, a função save referenciada a cima e usada para sobrescrever a padrão usada pelo models.Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele não está exportando o último cadastrado porque o método `save()` dentro do model funciona como `pre_save`. Para resolver esse problema você deve usar o signal `post_save`.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def faz_backup_de_livros(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    filename = instance.filename  # getattr(instance, 'filename', 'backup')
    get = serializers.serialize("json", Books.objects.all())
    bkp = open("backup/" + filename + ".json", "w")
    bkp.write(get)
```

Após você salvar um livro, será chamado o método `faz_backup_de_livros` que salvará o arquivo de backup.

```
book = Book()
book.titulo = 'Meu livro'
book.filename = 'meu_livro'
book.save()
```

Você pode saber mais sobre signals aqui: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Orion é bem bonita e concordo plenamente com a solução dele. No entanto, parte da  sua dúvida é como sobrescrever adequadamente o método save de uma subclasse de Model.

O que você faz está certo, não tem nada de errado com o a sua sobrescrita. Só que, para você obter o último livro salvo, você deve chamar o método da classe pai **antes** de fazer backup:

```
def save(self, filename="books", *args, **kwargs):
    super(Books, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    get = serializers.serialize("json", Books.objects.all())
    bkp = open("backup/" + filename + ".json", "w")
    bkp.write(get)
```

Da forma como você escreveu, o objeto só é salvo depois do backup, por isso ele fica incompleto.

Agora, cara, preciso te falar uma coisa, você já pensou o que vai acontecer com o seu banco se muitas pessoas salvarem livros ao mesmo tempo? Além disso, se o número de dados no banco for muito grande, não acha que o tempo de resposta para cada criação/atualização de livros será muito grande? E mais, o que acontece com o arquivo se dois livros são salvos ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Olá @Pablo, obrigado pelo teu retorno, sim, estou de total acordo com o teu modo de pensar, muita coisa poderia acontecer, porém, os dados que serão inseridos no bando de dados, são um tanto importantes, pensei em utilizar este meio de backup como segurança, caso aconteça alguma coisa com o banco de dados terei o mesmo salvo em um arquivo externo, e já que colocou estes pontos em pauta, por acaso você não teria uma forma mais viável(aconselhável) para se trabalhar com backup não?

Comment: @dhelbegor, existem várias maneiras para fazer isso, variando de situação para situação. Em função disso, há bastante material escrito (dê uma pesquisada por backup, recovery e replicação de banco de dados), pois, acredite, outras pessoas também possuem dados importantes. Possíveis soluções seriam replicar os dados em um outro  servidor e, bem como, criar um serviço para realizar dumps a cada x tempo.

Comment: @dhelbegor esse método de backup que você está implementando não é bom, o certo seria fazer backup do banco de dados. Caso você só queira o backup de registro de livros, poderia programar para salvar esse arquivo `json` uma vez ao dia e não cada vez que é cadastrado ou editado algo. Vale lembrar que seu código não está levando em conta que um livro pode ser deletado, creio que deveria atualizar o backup após um delete também.

Comment: Sim, estou de total acordo @Orion, esse foi apenas um teste que pensei em implementar, porém sabia dos riscos que o mesmo poderia trazer, estou vendo algumas coisas sobre standalone e outras opções do mesmo ramo, desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.